# Award bounty link does not have pointer mouse cursor

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, bounties

Items which can be clicked usually have a pointer mouse cursor when hovering over them, e.g. the vote arrows:

[image: downvote arrow with a pointer mouse cursor]

This is good. However, I noticed that since some recent (?) change in design, the award bounty link has the default mouse cursor, not the expected pointer cursor:

[image: award bounty link with the default mouse cursor]

Can this please be fixed? I'm talking about the link before awarding the bounty, shown only to the one who started the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. Hovering over the award bounty button now shows the pointing-hand mouse cursor:

[image]